# How to suppress window using wall clock time instead of event time in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The requirement is to send alerts if the expected 'final' event (identified from the evenType field in event payload) is not received for a key within a time window of say 2 minutes on the input topic. I tried using suppress() as follows:

```java
events
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2)))
  .reduce((oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, Materialized.as(....))
  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowClose(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
  .filter(event -> !event.getEventType().equals("FINAL") )
  .toStream()
  .foreach( /* Send that email! */)
```

based on [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/) blog.

However, since the suppress() is based on event-time, if the next or the 'final' event is not received, the time doesn't progress and the alert is not sent at all. How can I use wall-clock time with suppress() to emit the event when 2 minutes has elapsed based on wall-clock time?

Comment: hey were you able to find how to do this

Comment: @NikhilBansal not yet. Doesn't look like that is an option yet.

Comment: See [KIP-424: Allow suppression of intermediate events based on wall clock time](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-424%3A+Allow+suppression+of+intermediate+events+based+on+wall+clock+time) Note its current status is **Under Discussion**